# Android is is different in the code and ADB tools

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I've noticed a discrepancy between the Android_id values that I obtain directly from the code and those retrieved via the Android Debug Bridge (ADB). I'm trying to understand how this disparity can occur.

For Android 10 and later versions, I'm searching for a constant value to use. Due to changes in permissions for Android's operating system, using device_id is no longer feasible. Therefore, I wish to use the android_id as a replacement. Could you provide any insights or solutions to address this issue?

How i get it in the code:

```
var b = global::Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(global::Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, global::Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

how i get it from adb:

```
adb shell settings get secure android_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the method to get the ANDROID_ID on both Xamarin and Maui project by using the debug mode. I found that the ids are the same. But when I used the adb shell to get the ANDROID_ID, the id I got was different form the code. I also created an Android project on the Android Studio and tested it on the physical device, but I got the same situation that the ANDROID_IDs are different.

I check Android document about the [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID) then I find that On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, Values of ANDROID_ID are scoped by signing key and user. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes.

It can explain that why the ANDROID_IDs are different between the code and the ADB shell. Due to the signing key, they cannot be the same.